# How to run Firebase auth function in Android in Background using RX?

Tags: java, android, firebase, concurrency, rx-java3

I want to run my check user function in background, and rx do it. but a result of callback works only in main thread. the picture down shows it[image]

Can i do all of the code with signInWith() and addOnCompleteListener() in background thread, created by rx?